# Spring MVC form Validation on Page Load

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have following attributes in my pojo and on my jsp form:

Employee id:
Employee name:
Email:
Phone:
Account Name
Assessment name:
Level:
Date of assessment:
Time Slot:

**1.**
I a required to give a Error message beside each field as "**this field is required**". As far as i have studied, the `Bindingresult` checks for the error after getting inside the controller, but how do i give a pre error message when the page has been just loaded and no submit button has been clicked?

**2.** the three levels of assessment is dynamically populated, how to achieve this?

The document as reference:

https://i.postimg.cc/FztBS0LB/20190625-184751.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/kgMhWJ2q/20190625-184902.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/HsgNs4HJ/20190625-184909.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/FsVBfdsT/20190625-184916.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/kgjYc0S8/20190625-184921.jpg

Comment: learn `jquery form validation` and `regex`. try from here: [jquery form validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Then you can solve this front end problem easily